# Are there any programs for prototyping computer vision pipelines?

Tags: computer-vision, matlab-cvst, prototyping, vision

Are there any pieces of software available for prototyping computer vision pipelines that don't require coding.

I've tried this http://www.cassandra-vision.com/ but It's not very easy to use.

I'd like to make a pro's and cons list of different software as people add in the answers.

**Software**

***[Cassandra](http://www.cassandra-vision.com)***

Pros:

- Large coverage opencv
- Free Trial Version

Cons:

- Difficult to make pipelines

Price: $99

***[FlexCV](http://www.apulus.com/)***

Pros:

- Live changing of pipelines
- On screen previews
- Real time
- Free trial version

Cons:

- Not out yet
- un-mature
- Cannot export functionality

Price: Unknown but looks to be around 100GBP.

***[SimuLink (MatLab)](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink/)***

Please add in if you've used this.

Pros:

Cons:

Price: USD $135.00 (for matlab) + USD $39.00

**[Adaptive Vision](http://www.cassandra-vision.com)**

- Advanced previews
- Live parameters changing
- Free trial version
- Own image processing library (Adaptive Vision Library)
- Supports OpenCV library
- C++/C# code generator
- Writing your own filters e.g. in c++
- Easy GUI creator for your application

Comment: Beware - Any kind of environment that doesn't involve coding will be limited. You could try Simulink (Matlab)

Comment: Please can you give some pro / cons for simulink, I've not tried it

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this one, but have not tried it yet:

http://www.apulus.com/

From their website it says that you can do live pipelines and change settings whilst it is running.

The video looks pretty cool.

Comment: This looks very interesting... Shame it's not out yet

Answer (score 0):

**[Adaptive Vision](https://www.adaptive-vision.com)**

- Advanced previews
- Live parameters changing
- Free trial version
- Own image processing library (Adaptive Vision Library)
- Supports OpenCV library
- C++/C# code generator
- Writing your own filters e.g. in c++
- Easy GUI creator for your application

Comment: This looks like spam (i.e., an undisclosed bulk advertisement). If you are affiliated with Adaptive Vision, you must disclaim that. If not, please make that clear.

Comment: It was so late yesterday. I think now is better.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is completely free of charge for non commercial use in the current Release 11.5..

Comment: @SvaLopLop WHat do you mean with 'difficult to make pipelines'? WHat for problems did you have?

Answer (score 0):

Check out alwaysai.co. It is a very simple tool, with very clear instructions on how to train a CV model, and leverage API's to build your prototype.